# Adding multiple data with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can process my form values by targeting the form class `<form class="my_form_class">`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: my_form_class,
        context: this,
        success:function(data){

            // do stuff
        }
});
```

This works great.

But I want to add more data, so I tried:

```
data: { my_form_class, security : 'foo' },
```

It did not work. What am I doing wrong here? I tried:

```
data: { my_form_class : my_form_class, security : 'foo' },
```

And it obviously didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the definition of [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

You may use [jquery param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) and [jQuery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$('.my_form_class').serialize()  + '&' + $.param({security : 'foo'});
```

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($('.my_form_class').serialize()  + '&' + $.param({security : 'foo'}));
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: $('.my_form_class').serialize()  + '&' + $.param({security : 'foo'}),
      context: this,
      success:function(data){
        // do stuff
      }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('ajax error: ' + textStatus)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form class="my_form_class">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="name"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="surname">
</form>
<button id="btn">Submit Form with Ajax</button>
```

Comment: @Henrik Why would you accept the more lengthy solution, when there's a simpler one, which also has been posted eariler?

Comment: @nicael I was not aware that answer was posted earlier than this one, and at the time when accepting this one as correct, the other one had a typo with the quotes (which I believe that you addressed).

Comment: @Henrik Yep, there was a typo. Not something making the answer semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

Data of the form can be serialized, and data can be sent as a string :) 
I didn't test this, but it should work :)

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: $('.my_form_class').serialize() + "&security=foo",
        context: this,
        success:function(data){

            // do stuff
        }
});
```

Comment: I guess that should be appended to the `url`, not `data`.

Comment: Well yeah, because it's a get request it can be appended to url, but data should work too :) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax  look at data section, converted to query string if not already a string :)

Comment: @nicael I don't know how I forgot quotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `FormData` and loop over your data object and append it as

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('key', value);
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btn').on('click',function(){
    var value = 'abc';
    var fd = new FormData();
    var my_form_data = {
      fname: $('#firstname').val(),
      lname: $('#lastname').val()
    };
    for (var key in my_form_data) {
      if (my_form_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        fd.append(key, my_form_data[key]);
      }
    }
    fd.append('value', value);
    console.log(fd);
    jQuery.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: fd,
            context: this,
            success:function(data){

                // do stuff
            }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form_data">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname">
</form>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Another method includes using `.serialize()`. It can be used when you want data in query string as

```
var data = $('.my_form_data').serialize();
data += '&security=foo';
```

**AJAX**

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: data,
        context: this,
        success:function(data){

            // do stuff
        }
});
```